# iOS 11: UICollectionView: when appearing, scrolling happens

Tags: uicollectionview, ios11

when my UIViewController appears with a UICollectionView inside, the content scrolls up a little bit, when appearing.

I implemented `scrollViewDidScroll:` and I'm logging the `contentOffset.y`:

```
-20.000000
-20.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

This only happens on iOS 11 (simulator and device), not on iOS 10 or iOS 9. Anyone else experiencing this?

**EDIT** VERY WEIRD thing: this only happens when viewDidLoad is NOT called, so e.g. when the UIViewController already exists and it is popped onto again, but not when first showing that UIViewController...

Comment: Have you tried to disable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` on your ViewController ?

Comment: yes... additional info: please see my edit

Comment: Do you have a status bar shown in your ViewController ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In iOS 11, contentInset.top can be added in UIScrollView and subclasses (UICollectionView, UITableView) while status bar, navigationBar or other content appear in your view hierarchy.

This inset come from new adjustedContentInset property. (doc : [adjustedContentInset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902259-adjustedcontentinset))

To remove this extra inset, set content inset adjustment on your scrollView to never :

`[self.myScrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];`

More info in the WWDC17 video : [Updating Your App for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/) at 19'

Comment: that's it, thanks a lot! Still a bit weird as it wasn't necessary before some changes on my side (even on iOS 11), but unfortunately I don't know exactly what caused this. Nevermind, it works now, thanks!

Comment: I maybe understand when adjustedContentInset is fill or not : When your scrollView is attached to top/bottom of your controller view, adjustedContentInset is added, while when it is attached to top/bottom layout guide, adjustedContentInset is zero !

Comment: Thanks, it's so weird that start at contentinset 0 but stop at contentinset -64!! so i just found out this url

Comment: Avoid this. UIKit engineers specifically ask to not do this. Ref: https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/910656113653116928

"Instead, use additionalSafeAreaInsets to increase safeAreaInsets. Or set a negative contentInset to reduce/negate the adjustedContentInset." https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/910656175800119296

Comment: Thank you for the update @LuisAscorbe. For sure, you should adjust your scrollview content margin to safeAreaInsets to adapt your layout with the new iPhone X. However, sometimes you want your UIScrollView content to fill the entire screen.

Comment: Thank u very much.

Comment: Hi @vmeyer I have the same issue when dismissing a modaly presented view controller, but the presenting controller does not have any collection views or tableviews, it is just my nav bar that is pushed up by 20. Do you have any suggestions on that? Thanks

Comment: Hi @stan, please ask your question on a new thread and give us more info. Your problem may not be related to iOS 11.